# preg_replace() and \n in a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

For some reason, `preg_replace("/\\n/", "<br />", $string);` isn't working.

The string outputs in this format: `blah blah blah\nblah blah blah` even after the preg replace.

I want to change if for a `<br />`.

`nl2br()` doesn't work either, but as it's just text, I wasn't sure if it should.

The `preg_replace` function works on a word in the string. :(

Comment: It really output `\n`? You are sure, that it is a newline and not just a `\ ` and `n`?

Comment: no... this is why I figured that nl2br wouldn't work and why I had `\\n` in my preg replace to escape the `\`

Comment: I'm not inserting into a database... this is just to display on a website.

Comment: @Thomas: Try single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: felix... i have no idea why, but single quotes has worked! want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
str_replace("\n", "<br />", $string);
```

Comment: This may work with single quotes (and in fact, the preg_replace with single quotes does NOT work for my test script), but it doesn't explain why the preg_replace won't work.

Comment: It `DOES NOT` work with single quotes in most cases.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to replace the literal `\n` and not the actual new line, try:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("/\\\\n/", "<br />", 'Hello\nWorld');
```

Notice the number of backslashes. The double-quote enclosed string `/\\\\n/` is interpreted by the PHP engine as `/\\n/`. This string when passed on to the preg engine is interpreted as the literal `\n`.

Note that both PHP will interpret `"\n"` as the ASCII character `0x0A`. Likewise, the preg engine will interpret `'/\n/'` as a newline character (I am not exactly sure which one/s).

Comment: Because `'Hello\nWorld'` is single-quoted, you aren't testing replacement of an acutal newline.  This works: `echo preg_replace("/\\n/", "", "this
that");` (Replace the space between "this" and "that" by hitting Enter and closing the quote on the next line.).

Answer (score 3):

Try with the multiple lines modifier on your regular expression:

```
preg_replace("/\\n/m", "<br />", $string);
```

Comment: The other answer with the additional escapes is the proper answer in this case.  I was facing the same problem, the text has character '\' followed by character 'n' and the goal is to replace it with the single 0x0A newline character.

Comment: I don't see any anchors in your pattern.  Why are you recommending the `m` modifier -- makes no logical sense.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/35771159/2943403  I am DV this answer because it will only confuse and misinform researchers.  This advice should not be used.